# Installation of MS C# Visual Express fails mysteriously

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-express

I hate to resort to dumping problems on other people, and I'm sure this is a stupid problem that can be easily fixed, but it's really getting to annoy me and I can't figure it out.

Well I tried installing Microsoft C# Visual Express, but after a few minutes into the installation I got a "Windows Module Installer stopped working..." error.  It said the program "stopped working and was closed," but it appeared to stay up.  I restarted Vista, and although Windows Module Installer is gone, the same exact error pops up every couple of minutes or so.

Tried all the fancy ways to restart the service, still no luck.

The installation involved Microsoft .NET Framework v3.5, which Vista has been trying to update for a while now (with no attempts successful).  Maybe this could be part of the problem?  I searched it up on the Internet, and some related issues were caused by the ".NET Framework being corrupted." The solutions mostly involved re-installing the Framework, but that's just the problem - I can't re-install it.

In short:

1) Several failed automatic updates

```
a) Microsoft .NET Framework
b) Solutions require re-installation of the Framework
```

2) Attempted to download/install a new copy of .NET Framework

```
a) Download goes seamlessly, installation fails (no explanation given)
```

3) Attempted to install Microsoft C# Visual Express

```
a) Software requires .NET Framework
b) .NET Framework automatically included in installation
c) Download fails, error message appears with no explanation.
d) Windows Module Installer stays open, with no way to exit.
```

4) Computer restarted/rebooted

```
a) Windows Module Installer is gone 
b) Error messages still appear (And reappear when closed out), although the software isn't there anymore.
```

This has been really confusing for me.  Heh, I just want my computer back to the way it was before I even tried installing C# Visual Express now...

Any help is MUCH appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

(also, sorry for the messy formatting... This is my first time using this site.)

Comment: Can you look in the error log and post the results.  There should be a message about the failed install that will have a relevant error code.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but what is the error log called and where would it be located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

1) Run the Windows Configuration Utility

2) Go to the "Startup" tab

3) Make sure "Windows Module Installer" is UNCHECKED

4) Restart

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Windows update log files for any relevant error messages? Look in your Windows folder for "WindowsUpdate.log" or Windows Update.log".

Also the VS Express installer might leave a log file, possibly in your %TMP% folder. (Or they might be a command line option to create a log file, try calling the installer with /?)

Comment: Yes, it's rather strange... The following seems to turn up a lot.

"Attempt (number) to obtain post-reboot results"

Followed by this...

"WARNING: Failed to evaluate Installed rule, update ID = ..."

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run a diagnostic on your system memory, sometimes strange application behavior can be traced to a bad dimm.

There's such a diagnostic tool included with the Ubuntu live cds. You can access it through the menu after the cd boots, and it takes around 30-60 mins to run. There are probably some faster ones out there though.

Comment: Already did that.  It passed all tests...  Nothing out of the ordinary.